# Spontaneous B&B in Ireland

Tags: accommodation, ireland, northern-ireland, no-advance-plans

I am going on a road trip to `Ireland` and `Northern Ireland` and I would like to know if it is realistic to expect to find affordable B&B accommodation in Ireland. Affordable for me would be 50-70€ for a double room and I would like to decide where to stay spontaneously without booking via the established websites beforehand.

What is the best strategy to find accommodation in rural areas - do they use signs to offer accommodation or should I ask locals?

The route I would like to go is Dublin -> Belfast -> Antrim Coast -> Malin Head -> Derry -> North-West Coast -> Sligo -> Dublin. [Here is a little more detailed route.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zSBCd3g6ni6Y.kfdpzVp0jj34)

Comment: Stop in a pub and ask where in the area they recommend. Frankly this is good advice for finding pretty much anything.

Comment: The signage will be more than adequate given your proposed route.  It's well travelled.  Problems with signage will occur between November and June when they are insufficiently lit and the weather limits visibility.  There's some free B&B locator apps for the UK and ROI that you may wish to install before leaving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signage will be more than adequate given your proposed route. It's well travelled.

Problems with signage will occur between November and June when they are insufficiently lit and the weather limits visibility. There's some free [B&B locator apps](http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-bed-and-breakfasts) (also commercial grade) for the UK and ROI that you may wish to install before leaving.

Answer (score 8):

It may be more difficult than you think to find good accommodation spontaneously in rural Ireland. November is the off season and many B&B's could be closed and they would not be expecting passing trade.

While most Irish people are extremely friendly, knocking on random houses and expecting to be offered a bed is unlikely.

It would be better to book at least one stop ahead. Ask in your first B&B for a recommendation in the next town you're visiting.
The level of accommodation in Ireland is generally very high.

There are tourist board offices in most towns you are planning to go to, they will have a list of good accommodation providers.

Enjoy the trip, you've picked a good route, particularly Sligo!